# *args vs list as a arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, args

I just want to understand why we use `*args` when the same work can be done by `list` when we pass it as a argument. In which scenarios do we really need `*args`, where `list` as a argument will fail to do that operation.

```
list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def method1(args):
    for i in args:
        print(i*2)
method1(list)
```

```
list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
def method1(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i*2)
method1(*list)
```

I didn't find any differences. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yep, your examples are flawed, and don't quite showcase how you can pass a variable number of arguments in `*args`. (Your first example is only passing 1 item. that being a list.)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh In this case the OP know what they are (and also argument list unpacking), just don't know when they're useful. I think it's on topic to ask for example usage of a feature.

Comment: Aye, which i think the answer on the dupe target adequately addresses. But if the OP disagrees they can say so.

Answer (score 2):

```
def method1(args):
    print(args)
method1(5) it will print 5
method1() method1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
method1(2,6) TypeError: method1() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

To Avoid this situation we use

```
def method1(*args):
    print(args)
method1(1, 2, '3')
(1, 2, '3') print this
```

So *args is useful when we don’t know in advance how many arguments we need to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you can pass any number of arguments in the second case where it will throw error in the first case.

**Case 1**:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = 1
b = 2

def method1(args):
    for i in args:
        print(i*2)

method1(lst, a, b)
```

...fails with `'TypeError: method1() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given'`.

**Case 2 (i)**:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = 1

def method1(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i*2)

method1(lst, a)
```

...works.

**Case 2 (ii)**:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = 1
b = 2

def method1(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i*2)

method1(lst, a, b)
```

...works and so on, you can pass any number of arguments.